# Does the workflow differ between Flash Builder and Flash Professional?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

What is the workflow for creating an AIR application in Flash Builder and how does it differ from Flash Professional?

I am familiar with Flash Professional, but I'm trying top wrap my head around FB, but I'm coming from a stint in iOS development and Flash Pro is driving me crazy. (I have difficulty with classes mixed with the timeline, but I think that MXML might be a good substitute for the timeline.)

(Bonus: What are some good online resources for learning MXML?)

Comment: This is a hard question to answer thoroughly without spending lots of time.  The simple answer is: Yes -- the workflows are substantially different.  Flash Professional is more of a "designer's tool", while Flash Builder is more of a "coder's tool".  For example, in Flash Builder (formerly "Flex Builder"), there are no built-in tools for creating or manipulating graphics.  Everything is code-driven (mxml, and as3).  If you need to include complex graphics (eg from flash pro, or illustrator, or whatever), you import them using mxml/as3 code and/or metadata.

Comment: @Lee - I like your answer. I would appreciate if you posted it as an answer and expanded just a bit with some links to tutorials and getting started resources.

Comment: you can build your project out of pure AS3 class files without having to use the timeline (except for that document class "frame") if Flash Professional or MXML in Flash Builder.  personally, i don't use any timeline coding but i refuse to use Flash Builder to code my AS3 until they revamp that hideous UI.  lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer thoroughly without spending lots of time. The simple answer is: Yes -- the workflows are substantially different. Flash Professional is more of a "designer's tool", while Flash Builder is more of a "coder's tool".

For example, in Flash Builder (formerly "Flex Builder"), there are no built-in tools for creating or manipulating graphics. Everything is code-driven (mxml, and as3). If you need to include complex graphics (eg from flash pro, or illustrator, or whatever), you import them using mxml/as3 code and/or metadata.

In Flash Pro, you build graphic assets, place them on the timeline, and attach as3 classes to your assets.

In Flash Builder you build as3 classes (either in pure as3, or in mxml), and attach your fancy graphics to your classes.

There is no concept of a timeline in Flash Builder.  There is no concept of a stage.

The best tutorials and getting started docs are probably those provided by adobe on their "livedocs" site.  [start here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html).

You might pay particular attention to:

- [About Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4ce276-8000.html) -- and all the stuff linked from there.
- [Using Flex 4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/index.html)
- [Building AIR Applications with Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6b84a753ecd210fd-7fb8a08d12114b6a4cf-8000.html)

There are also some videos floating around on adobe's site somewhere.  I can't seem to find them right now... but if you prefer to learn that way...you'll find that several of those videos are pretty informative.

Comment: Don't forget about Catalyst, it's a big part of Adobe's Flex workflow strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin from here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc3ff6d0ea7785946-1ef579a712086c0951e-8000.html