# Conceptual differences between Flash CS5 and Flash builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder, flash-cs5

What are the conceptual differences between Adobe Flash CS5 and Flash Builder 4? Both seem to be equally useful for authoring actionscript enabled rich interactive apps both internet and desktop. What is the difference in principle of programming when using these two tools apart from that the UI is represented in Flash Builder in mxml?

Comment: [related S.O. question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4405910/416630)

Comment: @Lee: the related question is more like a "how-to", whereas what I'm asking is at a fundamental conceptual level, i.e what programming technique do the tools represent and where does it fit in the evolution of IDEs. For e.g, BB enabled "direct manipulation". Even Macromedia Director enabled that-animation sequences, the addition of a powerful scripting language called Lingo. Even the wikipedia page doesn't clarify that : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Director

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main difference is the target user. Flash CS is traditionally aimed at designers, whilst FlashBuilder is aimed at developers.

Most people generally agree that Flash CS should be used for designing graphic assets whilst FB would be use for the logic or programming of these assets.

It is generally accepted that Flash CS sucks as an IDE , so programmers tend to use other options such as FDT , FlashDevelop or Textmate to name a few, but there are other options.

This being said, the type of tools offered by both platforms differs greatly and one of the most powerful option is simply to use both, depending of course on your type of projects.

Game development for instance would be an ideal candidate.

As for mxml & FlashBuilder , please note that this only applies if you use the Flex framework. It is possible to develop pure Actionscript projects with FB, in which case your UI design could be done in Flash CS and brought into FB via the use of SWCs.

Finally , Adobe has greatly facilitated the workflow when using both platforms, it's not yet ideal but progress has been made.

Comment: Adobe introduced Catalyst CS5 for enabled "direct manipulation" and state based interaction and that is basically different from FB4. FB4 seems to be more powerful toolset than both, but has many limitations which is solved by not the tool, but the flex framework. A simple example would be creating an asynchronous state machine in Flash/Catalyst?